# Cannot find location of realease file

Tags: iphone, xcode4, osx-lion, osx-server

I've recently upgraded my XCode to 4.3.2 and also my OS to Lion so that my apps can work with IOS 5.1 plus. I'm now trying to upgrade a couple of old apps and I can't find where the app files are to upload to Apple.

The strange thing is that I can use Terminal to locate where my DerivedData folder is but when I try to use Finder the Library folder does not exist. Is there anything I am missing because Xcode tells me the path to me build file is /Users/SC/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/MyAppFolder/... but I cannot find it when using Finder. When I use Finder the Library folder does not appear even though it shows up when I use Terminal.

Comment: The User library folder is hidden by default on Lion. You can use though command+shift+g to navigate there, or go to "Go" menu and press option to show the user library item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you build and archive in XCode 4, you can go to Window>Organizer>Archives to view all your builds. You can validate and submit any build from there or right click and choose 'Show in Finder' to locate the app.

Ps. See my comment regarding the user library in Lion